Why doesn't "set -e -E" affect subshells in if conditions?
I have a multi-step check before deciding whether to execute some code. In words: "The code should be executed, if a guard file does not exist, and there are no files newer than a guard file."
I tried to express this as follows:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e -E -u -o pipefail
if (
    test -e ".guard"
    echo "Checking for changed source files..."
    find src -newer ".guard" -exec false \; -quit 
) then
    echo Building...
fi

set -e means, that the first failing command should fail the shell. set -E means, that subshells should inherit the behavior. And yet, even when .guard does not exist, the echo is executed.
Even more so, set -e seems to be ignored even if set in the condition-subshell.
>>> if(set -e; echo 0; false; echo 1;); then echo 2; else echo 3; fi
0
1
2

Why does this happen?

Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 and then [edit] your question to say you've read it but it doesn't solve your problem or delete your question if it does.

Also see How to prevent nested function failures being missed in bash.

Closed the question myself based on the link provided to Bash subshell errexit semantics and then highlighted by a stackoverflow feature. Which apparently deleted the comment suggesting that thread.

@EdMorton It did. But why would I delete the question? There's value in finding duplicates and references to sources on stackoverflow, as long as they are worded differently and point to an existing solution (that actually answers the question). After all, my original Google queries didn't lead me to those.
